# Xamarin SQLite How can i get values from my database to use them in my code?

Tags: android, visual-studio, sqlite, xamarin

Im working on visual studio 2015 with Xamarin and SQLite and i was trying to get values from my database so i could save them in variables in my code how can i do this?

My Code:

```
string folder = "/sdcard/Pictures/";
            var db = new SQLiteConnection(System.IO.Path.Combine(folder, "GameHubDB.db"));

            db.CreateCommand("SELECT Id FROM [Note] WHERE Username = '" + UsernameTxt.Text + "' AND Password='" + PasswordTxt.Text + "'", Id);
            db.Commit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a nuget package to create the SQLite connection.
Refer this link https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/data/databases/sqlite/